# KDE announces program name when I open an Emacs window

Tags: sound, kde, notification

I don't know why but suddenly KDE tells me whenever I open my Emacs window ... how can I tell it to shutup?  It only happens with Emacs so far.

Edit: My Thinkpad X220 runs on Kubuntu 14.04. I tried to set up Bluetooth to play music over an Bluetooth audio adapter, maybe I hit a key without knowing it.

I suspect there is some text-to-speach feature running?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide details, ex. OS, version, if and what you recently changed in your setup, and everything else that might help us help you.

Comment: @Jan Thanks. I've added some more informations. I suppose it's related to some accessibility feature.

Comment: Perhaps it's some accessibility setting meant as an aid to visually impaired people...

Comment: @Jan  Yes, and it was `orca`(screen reader) - possible a relict from the original Ubuntu Unity installation from which I switched to kubuntu (by installing kubuntu-desktop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's some accessibility setting meant as an aid to visually impaired people...

Comment: to make the answer complete: `orca` is a screen reader from the unity-control-center. It appears in the Utility menu of KDE but can only be stopped in KDE by either killing the process (eg. via Ctrl-Esc) or by invoking unity-control-center from a terminal and disabling it in the Accessability menu.